# Selecting C++ main function to build in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, git-submodules

I've a C++ project in eclipse which is version managed with git. I've a [git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), which is another project I've written in C++. The submodule has its main function and my project has its own.

Eclipse chooses other main (from the submodule) to compile when I press build. Is there a way to choose which main to build in eclipse?

**Update:** I'm still working on the issue. Excluding resources from the project didn't help either. Will answer the question when I solve it.

**Update 2:** Solved at last. See my answer.

Comment: You dont get an error saying there should only be one main?

Comment: Nope, it just builds the one from the submodule. The submodule's main function is not in the scope of the project. I need the libraries, so I symbolically linked the files to the project's scope.

Comment: What do you mean with "submodule"? Is another independent project?

Comment: Git has a feature called [submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), which imports another git repository inside the repository as, well, a submodule. You can use its files from the direct paths or by linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem, at last. The solution is not a simple and straightforward one, so I'm writing step by step:

1. First set your toolchain correctly from `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Tool Chain Editor -> Current toolchain`. It's `MacOSX GCC`or `Linux GCC` for me.
2. Set your correct project source path. I've symlinked the files from projects I imported as submodules to my project, so setting the correct source directory didn't exclude any required files from my project. Setting is at `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths & Symbols -> Source Location`. Make sure you exclude the other submodules and symlink the required files to your project.
3. Change the name of the artifact (binary, library, etc.) to something different than the `${projName}`, because when you have submodules, you will have a directory named as `${projName}` inside your build folder. Setting is at `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Build Artifact -> Artifact name`.

After making these changes, your project should build automatically. Looks like eclipse makes all necessary checks during build, but doesn't warn you about the problems. I had to see all these problems with running `make --always-build` inside the `Debug` folder.

Comment: Having a related issue and being looking for days. Thank you! My problem was that the main file was not included due to the source location error. Struggled to find a solution for
`In function LoopFillZerobss:
Debug/../startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s:109: undefined reference to SystemInit
makefile:36: recipe for target foo.elf failed
Debug/../startup/startup_stm32f407xx.s:113: undefined reference to main`